# Could a Google Extension search through your Operating System?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shellexecute

I have several Google Chrome Extensions downloaded from the Google Chrome Web Store. Are actions performed by Chrome extensions limited to the browser? I'm afraid a Chrome extension, could execute PowerShell commands and access files in my Operating System (e.g. Mac OS, Windows 10)?

Comment: No, extensions alone can't do it. You would have to install a separate utility that communicates with an extension via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: Nice. It would be scary if extensions alone could read a system's BIOS information

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.